# confused by inconsistent behavior of matrix

Tags: matrix

Here's my code block:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}
    <article>
        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
        <p>TEST EDIT 8</p>
        {% for block in entry.blogPost %}
            <p>heading - {{ block.heading }}</p>
            <p>sub heading - {{ block.subHeading }}</p>
            <p>accolade- {{ block.accolade }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

        <p>Posted on {{ entry.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</p>
        {{ entry.body }}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

And here's the error message I am getting on an inconsistent basis:

> Craft\MatrixBlockModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "heading"

I've tried to remove the other Matrix fields from the template, and just isolate on the 'block.heading' field, and I get really strange behaviors. Sometimes the template renders fine, and the dynamic value gets rendered by the page. Sometimes, with a different content entry, the same template gives the above error message.

I'm brand new to CraftCMS. Is there an obvious syntax mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have 3 block types in your Matrix, you need to check for the block type before trying to call an inner field.

```
{% block content %}
    <article>
        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
        <p>TEST EDIT 8</p>
        {% for block in entry.blogPost %}
            {% if block.type == 'imageCaption' %}
                <p>heading - {{ block.heading }}</p>
                <p>sub heading - {{ block.subHeading }}</p>
            {% elseif block.type == 'WhateverTypeAccoladeIsIn' %}
                <p>accolade- {{ block.accolade }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <p>Posted on {{ entry.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</p>
        {{ entry.body }}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

You should add that check before `block.accolade` as well for whichever block type accolade is in.